# Redis Connection refuse [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, predis

I just setup GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching packages. When running serve i got redis class missing. Then i run

```
composer required predis/predis
```

After that
I got this error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

and i got this error. Still working but I have not made any progress yet.
Any idea?

PS: i am working localhost with mysql. Not homestead.

Comment: Do you have the `redis-server` running?

Comment: No sir. There is no server information in the laravel doc. Is it necessary? I am working on localhost .

Comment: Yeah. Are you using Windows? Do you have redis installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, using windows. I just installed redis-win-3.2.100. Not yet installed.

Comment: When it's installed, go to the installation folder and try to find `redis-server.exe`. Run it and test if the error goes away.

Comment: Sure. If i can't fix again. I'll write here. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169432/discussion-between-jackowski-and-ali-ozen).

Answer (score 5):

Install Redis.

> https://redis.io/download or if the os is windows then https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases

Run Redis.

> $ src/redis-server or in windows then run redis-server.exe

Set the .env variables

> REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
>
> REDIS_PASSWORD=null
>
> REDIS_PORT=6379

Add redist code to database.php

> 'redis' => [
>
> ```
> 'client' => 'predis',
>
> 'default' => [
>     'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
>     'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
>     'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
>     'database' => 0,
> ],
> ```
>
> ],

Answer (score 0):

install latest version of redis from [This link is in GateHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)
then go to the ***.env*** file and change the *CACHE_DRIVER* to *redis*

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

then go to the path `config/database.php` and change the `REDIS_CLIENT` from `phpredis` to `predis`

```
'redis' => [
   'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
],
```

and clear config with this command : `php artisan config:clear`